# Rewrite rules for blocking URL access

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two sites,

**www.example.com** and **offers.example.com**

Now i want the site - **offers.example.com** to be accessed only through **www.example.com**

i.e., I dont want to give public access to **offers.example.com**...

Can i achieve this through rewrite rules?

or do i have to do this through PHP code?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 1):

you can not do that with php code as the second page viewed will not have the www. referer

you will need to build some sort of authentication with php or use .htpasswd and only allow users with logins to go there.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Thanks, but im not using any authentication.. its like a page in **www.example.com** fetches the content from **offers.example.com**.. So is there any rewrite rules i can write to check if the request is coming from a particular domain?

Comment: if you want something to not be available to the public, it needs authentication.